# How do I properly link multiple kinds of libraries in CMake?

Tags: c, cmake, makefile

I'm making a CMake project on MacOS, and my project requires `libraylib.a` and multiple different frameworks. This is what I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(RaylibHW)

# Adding executable
add_executable(rlhw my_app.c)
#linking C archives


# Linking frameworks
if(APPLE)
    add_library(libraylib STATIC libraylib.a)
    target_link_libraries(rlhw PRIVATE
    "-framework CoreVideo"
    "-framework IOKit"
    "-framework Cocoa"
    "-framework GLUT"
    "-framework OpenGL"
    )
    
endif()
```

I can link either the frameworks or the archive file, but since apparently it's doesn't work to use `target_link_libraries` more than once, I can't seem to do it.

Comment: `add_library` doesn't link with a library. It tells CMake that you want to create your own library. Is that really your purpose? You should use `target_link_libraries` like for any other library: `target_link_library(rlhw PRIVATE raylib)`

Comment: Also, you should not need to add the `-framework` option explicitly, on macOS CMake should be smart enough to add it for you. So e.g. `target_link_libraries(rlhw PRIVATE CoreVideo IOKit etc...)` should work just fine

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm fairly new to CMake, so I don't quite know the ins and outs yet.

Comment: At least for some of the libraries used here there should be a find module or package configuration file. Try finding some of the libs using `find_package`.

Comment: @petermayotte I recommend [Professional CMake: A Practical Guide](https://crascit.com/professional-cmake/) if you are new to CMake. It's what I used when I started learning CMake, and I can vouch it's a fantastic resource.